# Getting Started with GlassFish

Tags: java, eclipse, glassfish

This is a question for all you GlassFish users out there, in hopes that this can be a reference for future searches. I'm new to GlassFish, and am looking for a good place to get nice introduction. Can you direct me to some nice references or `Hello World` type of projects?

In my case, I'm using the [GlassFish plugin for Eclipse](http://glassfishplugins.java.net/) and hoping to use GlassFish as a server for some Java projects and would especially like references that pertain to this. I'll accept the first answer that gives a really good example or links to a really good example of this.

Here are some decent references I have found so far:

- [Example (from Blog Post) Using Enterprise Java Beans](http://edwin.baculsoft.com/2010/09/a-simple-java-client-server-application-using-ejb3-and-glassfish3/)
- [GlassFish Official Project Site](http://glassfish.java.net/)
- [GlassFish Wiki](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/GlassFish/GlassFishWiki)
- [Hello World Eclipse with GlassFish on Code Ranch](http://www.coderanch.com/t/499224/java-EJB-SCBCD/certification/run-Hello-World-example-Eclipse)

I found some fairly nice tutorials from Oracle on YouTube, but they're not quite the simple Hello World I'm looking for:

1. [Java EE 6 Development using GlassFish and Eclipse](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aBjlR9HoR50) - guides you through getting the plugin, initial server setup, and creation of a servelet.
2. [Building Web Apps with GlassFish and Java EE 6](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vuwXxuCjOm0) -

Comment: Stay away from _the Code Ranch_. There are _TONS_ of questions on this topic.

Comment: It's not a very good site in my opinion.

Comment: Okay, but based on what? (i.e. you think the users don't give good information, the site gives misinformation, it's formatting is poor, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the book:

Beginning Java EE 6 with GlassFish 3

[http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-GlassFish-Experts-Voice-Technology/dp/143022889X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143022889X)

There are tons of simple examples inside.

Comment: This could be very useful, thank you! Do you happen to have a link to any that are free?

Comment: http://www.apress.com/9781430228899 Google Preview will give you free access to some chapters. Source code for examples included in the book is also free. http://www.apress.com/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/338/